# How to export result as CSV file with Header from Cassandra DevCenter?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am using DevCenter 1.6.0. I know from unix system I can use copy command with HEDER = TRUE and can export all rows with header. But when I am using DataStax I am able to export al rows from result but unable to include header. How to export result as CSV file with Header?

Thanks !!!